# how to edit an existing MembershipUser in an asp .net application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

i'm using ASP.NET Membership and Roles with in my application 
i was wondering if there was a clean and explicit way to edit an existing user

now i know i could use the

```
              Membership.UpdateUser(MembershipUser user);
```

but i'm guessing there's a built in UI control which does this for me 
like the CreateuserWizard only for editing the currently logged in user

any ideas ?

thanks in advance 
eran.

Answer (score 0):

You could re-template a Wizard control to suit your update properties, but you'll still have to manually update the user. It's easy to just update the currently logged in user since you can use the [Membership.GetUser()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.getuser.aspx) method to get the current user and then change their details in code. (If you don't pass a user into the `GetUser()` method, it will try and retrieve the current user).

Answer (score 0):

No "eran otzer" there is no built in UI for updating an user, provided by asp.net. But you can make one of your as said by "keyboardP".

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is use Membership.GetUser method, populate a form with the user's properties, allow them to be modified, and have a SUBMIT button where you call the Membership.UpdateUser method. There is no built-in control that does this, but implementing one should prove trivial.